# Neo4J Error while comparing int values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My aim is to get country and continent with countries having population more than a value

So Cypher Query is

```
 MATCH (l:country)-[*]->(j:continent) WHERE l.Population>1990000 RETURN l,j LIMIT 15
```

This is giving Error

```
Don't know how to compare that. Left: "40377000" (String); Right: 1990000 (Long)

Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax
```

How to solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception message indicates, the property "Population" is of type "String", while 1990000 is of type Long. Make sure you store Longs in your "Population" property and your query will work as expected.

Maybe you can show a piece of your insertion script?

Comment: I Inserted using-
CREATE (a:country {population:'1452254'}) so, how this will become int or Longs

Comment: You should use CREATE (a:country {population:1452254}), so remove the "'" characters. Please accept my answer if it suits your needs.